# Show form in extension method and when form is closed remove unused resources and event handlers

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, extension-methods

I'm building two extension methods for DataTable. Both show content of DataTable inside new window (form). First one uses `ShowDialog` second `Show`. Below is my code:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static void ShowDialog(this DataTable dataTable, string title = null, Size? size = null, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler onCellFormatting = null)
    {
        using (var f = new Form())
        {
            f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow;
            f.Size = size ?? new Size(500, 300);
            if (title != null) f.Text = title;

            using (var dgv = new DataGridView())
            {
                dgv.ReadOnly = true;
                dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                dgv.MultiSelect = false;
                dgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
                /*other settings*/

                dgv.CellMouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
                    if (dataGridView != null) dataGridView.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
                };

                dgv.CellMouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
                    if (dataGridView != null) dataGridView.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
                };

                dgv.CellPainting += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (e.RowIndex != -1) return;
                    var dataGridView = sender as DataGridView;
                    if (dataGridView == null)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                    Point cursorPosition = dataGridView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
                    if (e.CellBounds.Contains(cursorPosition))
                    {
                        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.White, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.Red, Color.Green, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                        {
                            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
                        }
                    }
                    //paint rest, we only want to override background and borders
                    e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
                    e.Handled = true;
                };

                dgv.DataSource = dataTable;

                if (onCellFormatting != null)
                    dgv.CellFormatting += onCellFormatting;

                f.Controls.Add(dgv);
                f.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    [Obsolete("Use ShowDialog instead!")]
    public static void Show(this DataTable dataTable, string title = null, Size? size = null, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler onCellFormatting = null)
    {
        var f = new Form
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow,
            Size = size ?? new Size(500, 300)
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        {
            f.Text = title;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataTable.TableName))
        {
            f.Text = dataTable.TableName;
        }

        var dgv = new DataGridView
        {
            dgv.ReadOnly = true;
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgv.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            dgv.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
            dgv.MultiSelect = false;
            dgv.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
            /*other settings*/
        };

        dgv.CellMouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dgv.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        };

        dgv.CellMouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dgv.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        };

        dgv.CellPainting += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1) return;
            Point cursorPosition = dgv.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            if (e.CellBounds.Contains(cursorPosition))
            {
                using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.White, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.Red, Color.Green, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
                }
            }
            //paint rest, we only want to override background and borders
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            e.Handled = true;
        };
        dgv.DataSource = dataTable;

        if (onCellFormatting != null)
            dgv.CellFormatting += onCellFormatting;

        f.Controls.Add(dgv);
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

My question is: how should I dispose unneeded resources inside extension methods (in my case when form closes).
When using `ShowDialog` I have everything inside `using` block so this removes form and datagridview objects when they are not needed anymore (if I'm wrong please correct me)
Second method is using `Show`. I can't use `using` block, so how I should remove all event handlers and objects when form closes?
Should I even worry about that?

I'm using .NET 4.0 if that changes anything.

EDIT:
Based on @Hans Passant comment I've modified my code a bit. Now I have two extension methods that call same private method:

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static void Show(this DataTable dataTable, string title = null, Size? size = null, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler onCellFormatting = null)
    {
        Show(dataTable, title, size, onCellFormatting,false);
    }

    public static void ShowDialog(this DataTable dataTable, string title = null, Size? size = null, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler onCellFormatting = null)
    {
        Show(dataTable,title,size,onCellFormatting,true);
    }

    private static void Show(DataTable dataTable, string title, Size? size, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler onCellFormatting, bool modal)
    {
        var f = new Form
        {
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow,
            Size = size ?? new Size(500, 300)
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(title))
        {
            f.Text = title;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataTable.TableName))
        {
            f.Text = dataTable.TableName;
        }

        var dgv = new DataGridView
        {
            ReadOnly = true,
            AutoGenerateColumns = true,
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect,
            MultiSelect = false,
            EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false
            /*other settings*/
        };

        f.Disposed += (sender, args) =>
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Disposed");
            if(!dgv.IsDisposed) dgv.Dispose();
        };

        dgv.CellMouseEnter += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dgv.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        };

        dgv.CellMouseLeave += (sender, e) =>
        {
            dgv.InvalidateCell(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex);
        };

        dgv.CellPainting += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (e.RowIndex != -1) return;
            Point cursorPosition = dgv.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            if (e.CellBounds.Contains(cursorPosition))
            {
                using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.White, Color.Black, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var brush = new LinearGradientBrush(e.CellBounds, Color.Red, Color.Green, LinearGradientMode.Vertical))
                {
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.CellBounds);
                }
            }
            //paint rest, we only want to override background and borders
            e.Paint(e.CellBounds, DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentForeground | DataGridViewPaintParts.ContentBackground | DataGridViewPaintParts.Border);
            e.Handled = true;
        };
        dgv.DataSource = dataTable;

        if (onCellFormatting != null)
            dgv.CellFormatting += onCellFormatting;

        f.Controls.Add(dgv);

        if (modal)
            f.ShowDialog();
        else
            f.Show();
    }
}
```

I've created event handler for form disposed event:

```
f.Disposed += (sender, args) =>
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Disposed");
    if(!dgv.IsDisposed) dgv.Dispose();
};
```

So now when I close my form and it dispose I'm also disposing DataGridView.
It this enough to clear all resources that are unneeded when form closes?

Comment: You'll have to subscribe the form's Disposed event.  And think a bit about *exactly* what you are going to do, nothing in the snippet you posted requires any cleanup.  The form object is already disposed automatically when the window closes and the DGV is automatically disposed by the form's Dispose() method.  The *using* statement in the ShowDialog() method is not necessary.  In fact, ShowDialog() appears completely unnecessary since you don't use the dialog results at all and you ignore the return value of f.ShowDialog().

Comment: @HansPassant I've created two methods because I want two behaviors - I'd like to display my form as modal window (block rest of my application) -`ShowDialog` method, or display it as normal window - `Show` method. I didn't knew that DGV will dispose automatically, thanks fot tip. So can I use same code and have parameter that will indicate if window should be modal or not?

Comment: Sure. You are painting yourself into a corner, modal UI sucks pretty heavy and there's nothing you can easily do to make it non-modal since you can't get a FormClosed event out of the form. Necessary at least to disable a button or menu entry.  If it *has* to be an extension method then at least make it an extension for the Form class, pass the DataTable as an argument.

Comment: @HansPassant I've added modified version of code to my question. Please take a look at it. I know that modal UI sometimes sucks, but sometimes I want to have possibility to show something as modal, but I tr to avoid that as much as possible. It was easier for me to create version with `form.ShowModal` because of `using` blocks. But if second version of code is fine then I'll stick with it.